# Input fields lose focus on each value change in a complex Formik form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I'm building an app that will need a complex form generation (from json/js object).

Here's an example of what I'm building: [https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-form-wizard-test-vcj1t](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-form-wizard-test-vcj1t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

My problem is the following:

> all the input fields lose focus on every value change

---

The folder structure of the CodeSandbox project is the following (for easier code comprehension):

`./src`:

- `App.js` - main file with all the form generation (`generateWizardSteps` is the main function that does all the generation).
- `formSetup.js` - that's an object that defined form configuration. From objects like this I need to build dynamic forms. This object has the array of `pages` (these are the steps of the wizard), and each `page` has an array of `fields` (like input, select, checkbox etc). In its turn, each `field` has `props` property. `props` is what I pass to the React component as props.
- `formComponents.js` - this file contains all the form field React components that I use for generating my forms.
- `decorateWithFormik.js` - this file is just to make `App.js` a bit smaller. It's just the `useFormik` decorator.

---

The form is built using the [formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) library. Also, as I need a wizard-like form, I've found a nice library for it: [formik-wizard-form](https://github.com/mjangir/formik-wizard-form).

I've looked through the stackoverflow questions on similar topics but couldn't find something that could fit my needs. Many questions/answers are about the problem with dynamic `key` props, but mine are static as far as I can tell (they all are taken from the initial `formSetup` object).

Another thing that I've noticed is that my form gets re-rendered on every value change, but I'm not sure if this is a problem at all.

---

Could you help me to figure out what the problem is, why does it happend and how to make my form fields **not** lose focus?

Comment: I don't know why but it seems normal for other libs too. As for the solution, maybe simply add some `focus process` in `onChange` event handler, and if necessary, make it a HOC or service would be good enough.

Comment: @keikai could you be more specific, please? I've tried adding the `onChange` handler to my inputs with `inputRef.current.focus();`, however it doesn't seem to be the solution and, moreover, it redefines the `onChange` function provided by formik. I've also tried invoking the formik onChange and then do `inputRef.current.focus();` inside my `onChang`, however this also didn't have any effect

Comment: What happens is that on every onChange event `MyTextInput` unmounts and remounts and that's why the input is blurred.seems like `generateWizardSteps` causing that...

Comment: It looks like you are creating components within the render step. This means each time the form renders the child components are recreated, which causes them to lose focus. I recommend taking a step back and checking how `formik-wizard-form` does this in their examples: https://github.com/mjangir/formik-wizard-form/tree/master/examples/src

Comment: @SimonIngeson well, `formik-wizard-form` in their examples creates every `Step` separately, i.e. every step is predefined and is not created dynamically. If I try to create a wizard form using "static" `Step`s, then everything works fine. But I need to make it dynamic, i.e. to be able to generate such forms from different setup objects, that's why I can't use "static" `Step`s and need to create them dynamically inside a `map` function. It can't be that it's impossible to achieve that, there must be a way... But for now I can't find any solution or a way not to recreate components inside render

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-form-wizard-test-5g3c8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved the issue**

I've removed all the possible component creation code and moved everything inside the `component` props of the `Step` component provided by the `formik-wizard-form` library.

Here's my working solution: [https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-form-wizard-test-lz3x7](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-form-wizard-test-lz3x7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) (hope this will help somebody)

Many thanks to everyone in the comments section!

---

**Main insights:**

1. Losing focus means that the component `unmounts and remounts` every time.
2. This unmounting/remounting behaviour on every change was caused by the creation of components inside the `render` function of another component. Consequently, on every re-render the input components were created anew.

---

My final working code:

```js
const MyForm = props => {
  return (
    <FormikWizardProvider {...props}>
      {renderProps => (
        <Wizard {...renderProps}>
          <StepsList>
            {formSetup.pages.map(page => (
              <Step
                title={page.name}
                key={page.name}
                component={() =>
                  page.fields.map(field => {
                    if (
                      field.props &&
                      field.props.visibilityCheckbox &&
                      !props.values[field.props.visibilityCheckbox]
                    ) {
                      return null;
                    }

                    const fieldProps = {
                      formik: props,
                      key: field.props.name,
                      ...field.props
                    };

                    switch (field.type) {
                      case "input":
                        return <MyTextInput {...fieldProps} />;
                      case "radio":
                        return <RadioButtonGroup {...fieldProps} />;
                      case "checkbox":
                        return <MyCheckbox {...fieldProps} />;
                      case "select":
                        return <MySelect {...fieldProps} />;

                      default:
                        return null;
                    }
                  })
                }
              />
            ))}
          </StepsList>
          <ButtonsList>
            <PreviousButton />
            <NextButton />
            <SubmitButton />
          </ButtonsList>
        </Wizard>
      )}
    </FormikWizardProvider>
  );
};

export default decorateWizardWithFormik(MyForm);
```

Comment: Just yesterday I was reading on Reddit that people unhappy that formik re-renders on every input which slows down performance with big forms. New kid on the block now is https://react-hook-form.com/